# Unable to work with Parquet data having columns with forward slash in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a Parquet file, I am able to load the parquet file in Spark SQL. But Parquet files have lots of columns with forward slash that is causing problem when I am trying a to get a data from table using those columns.
e.g. columns names: **abc/def/efg/hij**

```
parqfile.registerTempTable("parquetTable")
val result=sqlContext.sql("select abc/def/efg/hij from parquetTable")
```

throwing below error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'abc' given input columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash is a reserved character, you'll need to quote the column name in your SELECT using backticks, as follows:

```
val result=sqlContext.sql("select `abc/def/efg/hij` from parquetTable")
```